# Eprints3: 'ast' is not a valid repository identifier

Tags: apache, perl

Our production EPrints (3.3.15) instance has recently failed.

Nothing has changed regarding either the EPrints config or the Apache config, but on Sunday some errors appeared in the Apache error.log file:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------- EPrints System Error ----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
Can't read cfg.d config files from /opt/eprints3/archives/test/cfg/cfg.d: No such file or directory
------------------------------------------------------------------
EPrints System Error inducing stack dump
 at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints.pm line 145
    EPrints::abort() called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints/Config.pm line 252
    EPrints::Config::load_repository_config_module('test') called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints/Repository.pm line 447
    EPrints::Repository::load_config('EPrints::Repository=HASH(0x7fe00c0d1688)') called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints/Repository.pm line 153
    EPrints::Repository::new('EPrints::Repository', 'test', 'db_connect', 0) called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints.pm line 491
    EPrints::repository('EPrints=HASH(0x7fe00ce7b428)', 'test', 'db_connect', 0) called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints.pm line 581
    EPrints::load_repositories('EPrints=HASH(0x7fe00ce7b428)') called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints.pm line 397
    EPrints::post_config_handler('APR::Pool=SCALAR(0x7fe00c829928)', 'APR::Pool=SCALAR(0x7fe00c8297c0)', 'APR::Pool=SCALAR(0x7fe00c829880)', 'Apache2::ServerRec=SCALAR(0x7fe00c8297f0)') called at -e line 0
    eval {...} called at -e line 0
[Sun Sep 17 06:25:16 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_auth_kerb/5.4 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o Phusion_Passenger/3.0.12 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

(then there is a few hundred of these errors)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------- EPrints System Error ----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------
'ast' is not a valid repository identifier:
PerlSetVar EPrints_ArchiveID ast
------------------------------------------------------------------
EPrints System Error inducing stack dump
 at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints.pm line 145
    EPrints::abort('EPrints') called at /opt/eprints3/perl_lib/EPrints/Apache/Rewrite.pm line 62
    EPrints::Apache::Rewrite::handler('Apache2::RequestRec=SCALAR(0x7fe00c8297c0)') called at -e line 0
    eval {...} called at -e line 0
[Sun Sep 17 06:25:32 2017] [error] [client 46.229.168.67] File does not exist: (null)
```

I have no idea what happened. I just find it strange that the first error relates to it trying to load config for the `test` archive, which also exists beside our `ast` archive. Thereafter it's not recognising our `ast` archive.

Comment: One approach would be to build a new server, using whatever DR plan you have in place, or even better, server orchestration scripts if you have them. Then point the system that uses this server to the new instance, assuming it starts up.

Comment: Whilst this piece of advice won't help you immediately, it seems you have uncovered a substantial business risk, and once this service is restored, you should address that as a matter of priority. Having a server in your stack that is unmaintained (or with no internal expertise to administrate it) needs to be addressed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Does `/opt/eprints3/archives/ast/cfg/cfg.d` exist? If so, find out where the root config is (`/opt/eprints3/*`?) and see if it is referenced in there. Maybe you have a config key pointing to the wrong file?

Comment: nope it seems the config is as it should be, there is no other config at the root folder. all that exists is whats at the archive. i can also run `bin/epadmin test ast` and it tells me my config looks fine.

Comment: I would start looking for where `/opt/eprints3/archives/test/cfg/cfg.d` is referenced. It looks intermingled in your Apache config, which looks like it might be dynamically modified in this Perl app. I suggest you examine the Apache config and see what clues you can get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was an empty 'test' folder beside our 'ast' archive. The removal of this folder fixed the issue. The reason why this behavior only started now is still a bit of a mystery.